# How to get cookies saved in browser with python and Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

I'm getting to use the cookie that is already in the browser and use it in Selenium, I know you can't use it using Selenium only, but is there any library I can use to save cookies in json in a variable and use it in Selenium?  How can I extract the cookie saved in the browser with python?  not only Chrome but others also preferably.

This is my code currently:

```
option = Options()
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")        
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get("https://google.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
```

**How can I get the cookie from the browser, save it in json format and use it with Selenium?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pickle
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import time


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")        
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get("https://google.com")
time.sleep(5)
if os.path.exists('cookies.pkl'):
    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    driver.refresh()
    sleep(5)
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

pickle will help you save and add cookies. But, be sure to add them to the correct domain otherwise you might get errors.

Comment: But the Google page was just an example, I actually want to do it on another page, and the page that I use the browser's cookie on is a page that redirects me to login, that's why I need I need to use the cookie that's already in the browser

Comment: There is no issue with the above code. you have to know when to insert the cookies.

Comment: If I want to get the browser's cookie and use it on this page then will I get it? https://discord.com/channels/@me

Comment: Yes, you can. But, no one can guarantee that it will allow you to log in automatically as it depends on various factors including the domain you are trying to use the cookies on.

Comment: It doesn't work, because there is no `cookies.pkl` file so your code will save the file with cookies, but what cookie will it save if I'm not even authenticated?

Comment: That's not a complete code. You should add the below code just below the login code.

        `pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235466/discussion-between-dex12-and-praveen-kumar).